# Extract from html to excel specific lines

Tags: excel, extract

Help greatly appreciated!
I'm trying to automate as much work as possible. I need to copy a lot of product information from my suppliers web page to mine. Manual work have been a pain in the ass and now I thought that I could ask for your help,

I'm trying to extract - ProductNumber, ProductTitle, ProductDescription, ProductWeightFormatted, and from ProductImageContainer picture url's. As I need to add some of my own info I Wanted to get each product in one row with 5 different cells.
Have been thinking and searching for solutions for whole day but no luck.

[Site where I am copying info from](http://www.raptor4x4.net/contents/en-uk/d59_BUMPERS_01.html)

Thank You!

Comment: Just an FYI: this post doesn't contain any code snippet or work you've done and thus it is hard for us to point you to an appropriate solution. If you could provide any code (or functions in Excel) that you've been using we might be able to assist you in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using getElementsById, followed by innerText or textContent?
In your case it makes sense, as each product has certain div id.